# identify: Postscript delegate failed `filename.pdf': rKkP.cache @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/638

Tags: imagemagick, paperclip

I am facing an issue in generating thumbnails from a pdf file. I am using paperclip for this. Output of the identify command is below:

identify: Postscript delegate failed `filename.pdf': rKkP.cache @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/638.

Any suggestions on this issue?

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick only process *raster image* files, it cannot natively read and interprete PDF or PostScript files.

It needs [**`Ghostscript`**](http://downloads.ghostscript.com/public/) as its *delegate* to read and convert these formats to images.

Therefor you need to install Ghostscript, before the processing of PDF or PostScript files by ImageMagick and Paperclip can start to work.

Comment: brew install ghostscript in OS X

Comment: @hectorsq: Or, alternatively: `port install ghostscript` -- which some people prefer.